# How to obtain all the partitions in a set $A$ such that the union of these partitions equals $A$?

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I'm trying to make a visual proof on the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$. At the moment, I've created a figure to show that $b^2$ elements always constitute a square:

[image]

And I want to show that it's not possible to make a square with $2b^2$ elements but showing all possible trials of mounting a square with these number of elements. My guess is that I'll need something that allows me to contruct arbitrary partitions:

```
{a,b,c} → {{a},{b,c}}, {{a,b},{c}}, ...
```

Such that their union is always equals to `{a,b,c}` but I have no idea on how to do it. I've tried a few times with `Subsets` and `Partition` but I got no success until now.

Answer (score 4):

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];

SetPartitions[{1, 2, 3}]

SetPartitions[{a,b,c,d}]

(*

{{{1, 2, 3}}, {{1}, {2, 3}}, {{1, 2}, {3}}, {{1, 3}, {2}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}}}

{{{a, b, c, d}}, {{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{a, c, d}, {b}},
 {{a, b, c}, {d}}, {{a, d}, {b, c}}, {{a, b, d}, {c}}, {{a, c}, {b, d}}, 
 {{a}, {b}, {c, d}}, {{a}, {b, c}, {d}}, {{a}, {b, d}, {c}}, {{a, b}, {c}, {d}},
 {{a, c}, {b}, {d}}, {{a, d}, {b}, {c}}, {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}}}

*)
```

Comment: Of _course_ there's a Combinatorica for this.  I should have guessed.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to just partition into two pieces and not into something like {{a},{b},{c}} (which I assume you do, for that factor of 2)

you can do something like this:

```
allPartitions[list_] := Union @@ Map[
    Function[order, 
             Map[{Sort[order[[1 ;; #]]], Sort[order[[# + 1 ;; -1]]]} &, 
                 Range[0, Length[order]/2]]
            ], 
    Permutations[list]]
```

Then

```
allPartitions[{a, b, c, d, e}]
(* gives
{{{}, {a, b, c, d, e}}, 
 {{a}, {b, c, d, e}}, 
 {{b}, {a, c, d, e}}, 
 {{c}, {a, b, d, e}}, 
 {{d}, {a, b, c, e}}, 
 {{e}, {a, b, c, d}}, 
 {{a, b}, {c, d, e}}, 
 {{a, c}, {b, d, e}}, 
 {{a, d}, {b, c, e}}, 
 {{a, e}, {b, c, d}}, 
 {{b, c}, {a, d, e}}, 
 {{b, d}, {a, c, e}}, 
 {{b, e}, {a, c, d}}, 
 {{c, d}, {a, b, e}}, 
 {{c, e}, {a, b, d}}, 
 {{d, e}, {a, b, c}}}
*)
```